# Automapper - How to map list into dictionary

Tags: c#, automapper

I've a list of records from DB like:

> 1;Order1;Name1;10,99
>
> 2;Order1;Name2;10,99
>
> 3;Order1;Name3;10,99

In the view I must list the names separated by comma:

> Order1 contains products: Name1, Name2, Name3
>
> Summary: 10,99

Now I take a list of items and I group it by Order1 and then I use for loop where I join names

```
foreach (var order in orders.GroupBy(f => f.OrderId))
{
   var o = order.First();
   o.Name = string.Join(", ", order.Select(f => f.Name));
   items.Add(o); // this items are being mapped
}
```

at the end I map this list by automapper. I don't like this solution. Is it somehow possible to move this "name joining" do automapper?

Comment: how did you define items?

Comment: What is your current Automapper configuration? Please provide a bit more context.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to do the following (i not yet tested)

```
foreach (var order in orders.GroupBy(f => f.OrderId))
{
   var strOrderId = order.Key;
   var strNames = string.Join(", ", order.Select(f => f.Name));
   Console.Writeline("{0} contains {1} ", strOrderId, strNames);
}
```